# wcf - .net 3.5 client and .net 4.0 routing service

Tags: wcf

is it possible for a .net 3.5 application to communicate smoothly with .net 4.0 routing wcf service?

should i get in to any problems when trying to perform this operation?
can i work with the simple channel factory?

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by communicate.

The application will be able to call the service over WCF.

It will not be able to call the dll directly, the dll runs in an application pool and the application pool is tied to a specific version of the framework.